# isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript is never called when setting windowScriptObject

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have tried to follow the Apple article [Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-120402) to give the JS in a WebView access to a few objective-c functions.

Ended up with a middlelayer object that looks like this:

```
// FILE: RTFInterop.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@protocol RTFInteropDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface RTFInterop : NSObject

- (id)initWithWebView:(WebView*)webView andDelegate:(id<RTFInteropDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)onHeightUpdated:(int)height;
- (void)onAnswerBlocksUpdated:(NSString*)answerBlockJSON;

+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel;
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector;
+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name;

@end

// FILE: RTFInterop.m

#import "RTFInterop.h"

@implementation RTFInterop {
    WebView *webView;
    id<RTFInteropDelegate> delegate;
}

- (id)initWithWebView:(WebView*)aWebView andDelegate:(id<RTFInteropDelegate>)aDelegate {
    self = [self init];

    if (self) {
        webView = aWebView;
        delegate = aDelegate;
        [webView.windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"RTFInterop"];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    NSString *name;

    if (sel == @selector(onHeightUpdated:)) {
        name = @"onHeightUpdated";
    } else if (sel == @selector(onHeightUpdated:)) {
        name = @"onAnswerBlocksUpdated";
    }

    return name;
}

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)sel {
    if (sel == @selector(onHeightUpdated:)) {
        return NO;
    } else if (sel == @selector(onHeightUpdated:)) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name {
    return YES;
}

// Called from JS
- (void)onHeightUpdated:(int)height {

}

// Called from JS
- (void)onAnswerBlocksUpdated:(NSString*)answerBlockJSON {

}

@end
```

And example usage is something like this:

```
self.webView = [[WebView alloc] init];
self.interop = [[DXRichTextInterop alloc] initWithWebView:self.webView andDelegate:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/example/dev/testembedd.html"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

The webView is shown properly, but the problem is that it does not seem to inject the JavaScript, break points in `isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:` are never hit.

**Question:** Is there some requirement when embedding as JS that isn't included in the article that I have missed? Such as when in the WebView lifecycle you can inject JS. Or is it simply some other mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, `webScriptNameForSelector`, `isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript` and `isKeyExcludedFromWebScript` are called when the JS tries to call the injected functions or access injected keys.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @JasonHarrison It was to call the function in Javascript, it is first when you do that the objective-c injector methods are called.